# Data conversion in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have  two columns in oracle table which of type NUMBER (38,10) and NUMBER (9). But values in that column are integers only.

For eg

```
COL1     COL2 

165261   638216
```

below mentioned code is being used to read data

```
source_df =self.spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", self.Oracle_jdbc_url).option("dbtable", "(select C1,C2  from schema.table where rownum <=2 ) ").option("user", self.Oracle_Username).option("password", self.Oracle_Password).option("numPartitions",2)\
        .option("lowerBound", 1)\
        .option("upperBound",100000)\
        .option("partitionColumn", "c1").load()

source_df.show()
```

Output is coming as **100522.0000000000**

But i want it to get stored as 100522 only .

Comment: You can `round` the column or cast it into integer

Comment: Hello @walking thanks for replying . When you say round the column or cast , so do I need to run is while reading data or do I need to add additional step to cast or round it and then show the result .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do [**`round()`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#round) after you read the data from jdbc and if your data contains decimal values then use **`cast`** to decimal.

**`Example:`**

```
source_df = source_df.withColumn("ORG_CODE", round(col("c1"),0))
source_df.show()

from pyspark.sql.types import *
#incase if your data contains decimal values then cast to decimal(38,10)
source_df = source_df.withColumn("c1", col("ORG_CODE").cast("decimal(38,10)"))
```